# External Server mysql_connect No route to host

Tags: php, mysql, docker

I am running PHP inside of the official PHP Docker container found here: https://github.com/docker-library/php

I am trying to get my application to connect to an external MySQL server using the old `mysql_connect` function as that's what our application uses. When trying a very simple script it yields the error: `Warning: mysql_connect(): No route to host`.

I have verified that using the standard MySQL CLI that I can connect to the intended server from inside the docker container so know that my container can speak to the outside world with no issues. Similarly things like `file_get_contents()` work with no issues indicating no DNS issues.

Both the host and the container have their DNS set to 8.8.8.8 and the container was launched with the `--net host` flag.

For reference here is the script I tried:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("my-external-rds.amazonaws.com", "user", "password") 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue? I can provide any information necessary.

Comment: I don't use `mysql_connect` so I don't know if it could be a problem at all, but probably `mysql_connect` cannot handle connections to ipv6 and the hostname only resolves to ipv6.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I checked and my actual hostname appears to be using IPv4.

Comment: Does it work if you use that ip directly instead of the hostname?

Comment: currently i'm facing the same problem after 4 years!